# Finding the sum of the series using differentiation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, computer-science, generating-functions

[image: Porf. Tom leighton teaching derivitive method to compute the sum of a series]

How can the left hand side be differentiated when it is defined only over integers and is not continuous and hence not differentiable?

Comment: You are misreading it. Differentiation is with respect to $x$, and the RHS basically amounts to using $(f/g)'=(f'g-fg')/g^2$.

Comment: What is defined over integers?

Comment: @dxiv - yes the differentiation is wrt x. But x^i is defined (here) only over integers. Which should cause problems with differentiability of f(x) = summation(x^i)

Answer (score 2):

It is not stating that the function defined over only the integers. The function itself is just a series of polynomials where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is differentiable. $i$ is just an integer parameter to yield your polynomial series.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (x^i)=1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n$$

Since $x \in \mathbb{R}$, this can be differentiated to give:

$$1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}$$

Which is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (ix^{i-1})$$

Which was the answer obtained.

Comment: I was completely seeing it very wrongly. got it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

One may recall that
$$
(f_1+f_2)'=f'_1+f'_2 \tag1
$$ giving by induction
$$
(f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_n)'=f'_1+f'_2+\cdots+f'_n \tag2
$$ where we assumed all $f_i$ differentiable on a given set.

Observe that you can rewrite $(2)$ as follows
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\right)'=\sum_{i=1}^nf'_i. \tag3
$$

Now take $f_i$ such that $f_i(x)=x^i$, then $f'_i(x)=ix^{i-1}$ and $(3)$ rewrites
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx^i\right)'=\sum_{i=1}^nix^{i-1}. \tag4
$$ Hoping it helps.